# О постановке запятой в СПП

Tags: пунктуация

Относится ли здесь "заметим" только к первому простому предложению?

Заметим, что при установке нескольких предохранительных клапанов достаточно обеспечить выполнение данного требования хотя бы для одного из них, давления начала открытия остальных могут быть настроены на большее значение (,) и клапаны будут срабатывать по мере развития аварийной ситуации.

Comment: "Заметим" будет логически относиться ко всему, даже если вместо первой запятой поставить точку (так намного легче читается - по крайней мере, с первого раза :) ). Запятая нужна (два предложения с разными подлежащими + причинной связью).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое – не простое. "Достаточно обеспечить" и "давления могут быть настроены" – вот основы.
Запятая, несомненно, нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое. А я думала, "давления начала открытия..." можно дать отдельным предложением, так как это уже другая часть, и тогда запятая действительно будет нужна в обязательном порядке.